# Gradient color background on matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm plotting a spider chart in matplotlib, and want the background to be a colour gradient, but I can only see how to set the background to a solid colour. I want the gradient going radially (e.g. [this](https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9448490/thumb/1.jpg)). Is there a way to just write `set_facecolor('name_of_colormap')`?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
r = [2, 1.5, 4, 3, 0.5, 2.5]
theta = [(2*np.pi)/6*i for i in range(6)]
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N") # Put 0 at the top
ax.set_rticks([])
ax.set_thetagrids([i*180/np.pi for i in theta[:-1]])
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)      # Make angles go clockwise
ax.set_xticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'])
ax.set_facecolor("green")
ax.plot(theta, r, 'k')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax.pcolormesh` to achieve that. Note that in the following example I have applied a cyclic color map and `colors` defines the the way color is going to be mapped to the colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply
import matplotlib.cm as cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
r = [2, 1.5, 4, 3, 0.5, 2.5]
theta = [(2*np.pi)/6*i for i in range(6)]
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N") # Put 0 at the top
ax.set_rticks([])
ax.set_thetagrids([i*180/np.pi for i in theta[:-1]])
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)      # Make angles go clockwise
# ax.set_xticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'])
N = 500j
rr, tt = np.mgrid[0:4:N, 0:2*np.pi:N]
colors = rr / rr.max()
ax.pcolormesh(tt, rr, colors, cmap=cm.hsv, shading="nearest")
ax.plot(theta, r, 'k')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thanks. Although it has hidden the axis I had, even after I move `set_thetagrids` to after the `pcolormesh` line.